# arduino find text in webpage

Tags: arduino

I am trying to make an arduino weather alert, from [this website](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Melbourne,au)
and I need to find the contents of the quotation marks in "weather" after "main". I have looked for a text finder, but the one on the [arduino website](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/FindText) but it's so undescriptive that it might as well not exist.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
char server[] = "api.openweathermap.org";  

IPAddress ip(192,168,1,77);

EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }

  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  delay(1000);

  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    client.println("GET /data/2.5/weather?q=Melbourne,au HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: api.openweathermap.org");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } 
  else {
  }
}

void loop()
{
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    client.stop();

    while(true);
  }
}
```

and it returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sun, 07 Jun 2015 21:17:44 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
X-Source: redis
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST

1d2
{"coord":{"lon":144.96,"lat":-37.81},"sys":{"message":0.0117,"country":"AU","sunrise":1433626204,"sunset":1433660872},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"Sky is Clear","icon":"01n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":284.532,"temp_min":284.532,"temp_max":284.532,"pressure":1011.27,"sea_level":1030.68,"grnd_level":1011.27,"humidity":80},"wind":{"speed":4.43,"deg":331.501},"clouds":{"all":0},"dt":1433711139,"id":2158177,"name":"Melbourne","cod":200}

0
```

for this output I want it to say: `Clear`

Comment: I'm not sure if there's already a text finder. But you can always make one yourself. All you need to do is, parse the buffer one by one checking character by character. Should not be very difficult. It would be a couple of nested ifs for example, if(buff[i++]=='\"'){ if(buff[i++] == 'm') { ... }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very easy way to get the data you want is with [TextFinder](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/TextFinder) from the Arduino playground. I believe this should work. Note that I haven't tested it, so fingers crossed.

Add this at the begining

```
#include <TextFinder.h>
#include <String.h>
String result = "";
TextFinder finder( client );
```

Then modify your loop() to this

```
if (client.connected()){
  finder.find("\"weather\"");
  finder.find("\"main\":\"");
  char c = client.read();
  while(c != '\"'){
    result += c;
    c = client.read();
  }
  Serial.print(result);
}
if (!client.connected()) {
  Serial.println();
  client.stop();
  while(true);
}
```

**More info below if you're interested.**

The response you're getting is json, to properly interpret it you need a json parser. I found a library on github: [ArduinoJson](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson) that parses json on the arduino. It seems quite easy to use too. If you need help with it, you can browse it's [wiki](https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/wiki)

Before you start parson the json, you need to first strip the header from the response. To do that you could keep reading the characters until you get a double CRLF (\r\n\r\n)

Comment: WARNING: I am not very advanced!

Comment: I tryed it but it sayed:
weather.ino:7:20: error: 'client' was not declared in this scope
weather.ino: In function 'void loop()':
weather.ino:44:17: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
Error compiling.

Comment: Ok, now it just says:
weather.ino: In function 'void loop()':
weather.ino:44:17: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
Error compiling.

Comment: I moved:
String result = "";
TextFinder finder( client );

Comment: @Hazzdood try replacing while(c != "\""){ with while(c != '\"'){

Comment: uploaded, but did nothing except flash the ethernet lights.

Comment: @Hazzdood I made a mistake in the finder.find, I updated them, try the new code